# ....not a recognized table hints option. .... ensure that your database compatilbility mode is set to 90."

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, compatibility

I'm getting frequent errors in code where it says

> CustomerSales is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a parameter to a table-valued function, ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90.

It's happened with several other tables eg Hires, CustomerNumbers, etc.

I came across this suggestion on google, but I'm not sure if it's the best thing to do? Or what may have caused the error in the first place?

Can anyone please advise what is likely to cause this type of error and the best solution?

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = { 150 | 140 | 130 | 120 | 110 | 100 | 90 }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver15

An example of the code I get the error with is this:

```
WITH CustomerAges AS 
(
    SELECT 
        P.FirstName, P.LastName,        
        FLOOR (DATEDIFF(DAY, PD.BirthDate, GETDATE()) / 365.25) AS AGE          
    FROM 
        Sales.vPersonDemographics PD        
    INNER JOIN 
        Person.Person P ON P.BusinessEntityID = PD.BusinessEntityID
)
SELECT 
    *, 
    CASE
        WHEN Age IS NULL THEN 'Unknown Age'         
        WHEN Age BETWEEN 0 and 17 THEN 'Under 18'       
        WHEN Age BETWEEN 18 and 24 THEN '18 - 24'       
        WHEN Age BETWEEN 25 and 34 THEN '25 - 34'       
        WHEN Age BETWEEN 35 and 49 THEN '35 - 49'       
        WHEN Age BETWEEN 50 and 64 THEN '50 - 64'       
        ELSE 'Over 65'      
     END AS AgeRange  
 FROM 
     CustomerAges
```

Comment: It would probably help if you could identify which queries raise this warning.

Comment: The best way to fix it is to find the statement (or statements) that produce the error and then examine your application code to understand why it generates / executes such statements.

Comment: Hi GMB, I've just posted the code giving me the error. If you could let me know which button I should press to make the code easier to read on the forum, it would be appreciated. Your thoughts on why the code error may be being generated would also be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you have an application generating its own SQL code and it's trying to run multiple SQL statements within a single batch. Try updating your SQL generator such that it opens CTEs using `;WITH ...` instead of just `WITH ...`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, AlwaysLearning. I tested that out manually, by putting a semi-colon in front of the my statements starting with 'WITH' and the errors disappeared! So thank you for that suggestion! I was able to create Common Table Expressions before, without having to put the semi-colon in front of the 'WITH,' however. Do you know what would cause the application to generate its own SQL code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If adding the `;` fixed the error it's because the code immediately preceding the CTE wasn't terminated correctly, i.e.: `select * from dbo.Foo with CustomerAges as (...) ...` should be two separate statements `select * from dbo.Foo; with CustomerAges as (...) ...`

Answer (score 0):

Check the `COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL` and set it to 120; it works for me.

```sql
SELECT  name, compatibility_level
FROM    sys.databases
WHERE   name LIKE '%DBName%';

ALTER   DATABASE [DBName] 
SET     COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 120
```